# batch script: newLine doesnt not appended to email but works in echo testing

Tags: email, batch-file, cmd, newline

So I'm new to batch scripting but I need to do something simple with it to finish my project.  I am trying to send an automated email every hour (already done) to several users with a message and the attached report.  I have the code for that mostly done but it looks sloppy and I haven't been able to fix it.  Here is my code below

```
echooff 
cls
rem This creates a new email message with an attachment for testing purposes.

rem Setting new line character
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set NL=^


rem TWO empty lines are required
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes
notes mailto:username@whereyouplease.com?subject= My Test Email Subject^
&body= cmd test email: !NL!!NL!^
&attach=C:\Users\F400318\Desktop\testDB2.xlsx
```

OUTPUT:

email body: cmd test email: [attachment here]

WANTED OUTPUT:

email body:     cmd test email:

```
            [attachment]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a variable representing a new line character, use the following:

```
set "NL=& echo."
```

Then a command like:

```
echo The first line%NL%The second line%NL%The last one!
```

would output:

```
The first line
The second line
The last one!
```

I am not sure if this will solve all the problems you are having with your script. I don't quite understand what your script is doing, particularly the last three lines. For example, the line

```
notes mailto:username@whereyouplease.com?subject= My Test Email Subject^
```

will throw an error because `notes` is not a valid command prompt command. For general tips on getting started writing batch scripts, I have found http://ss64.com/nt/ to be very helpful.

Hope I could help!

Comment: Thanks, i've tried that solution, it actually works alone just fine if you make it as an example script but it wouldn't work with the notes part as well, something strange that I can't explain, thanks though